# How to send "post-request" to site and log in [JAVA]

Tags: java, post, jsoup

I'm trying to register on site URL = http://flyner.com/signup via jsoup

[image: Request analyze]

What am I doing:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(URL)  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").execute(); 


             document = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                    .data("email", mail)
                    .data("pass", password)
                    .data("agree","1")
                    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                    .post();
```

but nothing happens.

I think, that i need to add to my data also "fkey", "skey", "dkey", and may be "ts",but how can i get it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you get all relevant info (session-id, tokens, etc.) to send along a POST-request for login with a previous GET-request request to the URL that renders the login-form. This is general advice and I did not look into the URL you mentioned so I don't know what other parameters are needed. A good help is to log all network traffic from first GET to final POST request. You can turn on the option to keep all network traffic in the developer tools of a browser of your choice.

Comment: I got the answer, that without headless browser its impssible to do.